# Why were the commentary literature like Talmud Mishnah not written down until 8-10th century?

Tags: mishna

What is the reason behind the Mishnah, talmud not written until about 8-10th century AD? This delay in the writing leads to ambiguity and speculations about the actual origin of the interpretations. Is there a specific reason given by someone, or it's just because these commentary-traditions were never supposed to be written?

For example about [Pirkei Eliezer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_De-Rabbi_Eliezer):

> Isaak Jost first noticed the inclusion of 8th century interpolations. According to Jewish Encyclopedia it was composed in Italy shortly after 830.[6] Scholars unanimously agree that Pirke de-Rabbi Eliezer is a work of the 8th or 9th century.[7][8][9]

Comment: The Mishna is halachic literature. The Talmud is more commentary-oriented. That said, there is a disagreement about when both were first written down, the different views spanning centuries. The base of the dispute is the question of when officially Oral Torah was finally allowed to be written down.

Comment: See here Rabbi Yehoshua Falk's explanation: https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/studies-halakha/philosophy-halakha/written-law-and-oral-law